# SwiftUI views - computed property vs struct

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

To encapsulate SwiftUI subviews, you can use computed properties like the following:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
            footer
        }
    }

    var footer: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or you can create dedicated `View`-conforming structs:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
            MyViewFooter()
        }
    }
}

struct MyViewFooter: View {
    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

How (if at all) are these cases handled differently by SwiftUI's refresh/diffing mechanism?

Comment: Computed property is the same as built-in in body, but separated view how own life/refreshing cycle.